# How to prevent IE mode in Edge

Tags: internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ie-compatibility-mode

One of website users for some reason is loading my website in IE mode in their Edge Version 113.1774.50 (Official build) (64-bit) and I am struggling to figure out how to prevent this from happening.

I have following meta tag already included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
    <title>.....</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
....
```

And this user already tried disallow sites to be loaded in IE mode (in Edge Default Browser settings), however the website is still getting loaded in IE mode. This is user agent that I can see in server logs:

```
Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
```

**Question:** Does anyone know what I am missing here or what else I can do to stop website from being loaded in IE mode?

Comment: Did you made sure that the meta tag was at the top of your head?

Comment: @imvain2 it actually comes 2nd, after title (I updated my question in include top first lines of html). Confusing part is that it's the only client that has this problem, other clients that have the same browser version do not use IE mode. So I wondered if there is something else on client side that can force a website to load in IE mode.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a modern HTML5 doctype, instead of a XHTML one?

Comment: @Evert not too sure to be honest, it is a legacy website so I was trying to avoid making changes like that as it would require full regression testing. Do you think it might be a reason of certain clients switching to IE mode?

Comment: Please visit `edge://settings/defaultBrowser` and set **Let Internet Explorer open sites in Microsoft Edge** to `Incompatible sites only`. Please visit `edge://policy/` and see if the `InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList` policy has site list assigned. If yes, try to check the site list file and see if your site URL is listed in it. If you found one, you could remove it. refresh the policies and make sure Edge uses the latest policy, then again check for the issue. If it is happening for a specific user, try to reset the Edge browser and see whether it helps to fix the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT that's exactly what the issue was, InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList was pointing to an xml file which had my website listed for some reason. If you can make it as an answer I will mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: @Vladimirs , Its great to know that you have found the cause of the issue and the suggestion was helpful to you. I have posted the suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please visit `edge://settings/defaultBrowser` and set **Let Internet Explorer open sites in Microsoft Edge** to **Incompatible sites only**.

Please visit `edge://policy/` and see if the **InternetExplorerIntegrationSiteList** policy has site list assigned.

If yes, try to check the site list file and see if your site URL is listed in it.

If you found one, you could remove it. Refresh the policies and make sure Edge uses the latest policy, then again check for the issue.

If it is happening for a specific user, try to reset the Edge browser and see whether it helps to fix the issue.